Методы объединения фотографий и текста в одном файле C++
Суть задачи:
Имеются фотографии, хранящиеся в папке на компьютере. Программа на языке C++ выполняет обработку и выдает результаты в формате строк. Необходимо для удобства чтения человеком представить всю информацию вместе с фотографиями в одном файле. Желательный вид файла:
{

[photo]

[text]

},

{

[photo]

[text]

}, и так далее.

Вопрос:
Какие форматы можно использовать для этих целей? Хочется пойти по пути наименьшего сопротивления, так как задача срочная. Задумывался насчёт html, но я его не знаю и возможно есть варианты лучше/проще?

PDF, Word, Excel, RTF может быть

SQLite?

Markdown проще всего. Например так:
![](путь/до/картинки)

текст

---

![](путь/до/картинки)

текст

---


Спасибо большое! И вправду очень удобно. Подскажите, почему markdown не поддерживает абсолютные пути до файлов?

@kreppid Хз....
